# python array create function

Tags: python, массивы

i’m have some data
(есть входной массив)

```
x = np.array([
[-1.8, 1.12, 50.6],
[-3.2,4.8,6.8],
[2.6,14.04,16.8],
])
```

есть массив соответствий (МАСКА // фильтр)

```
cons_data = np.array([
[1,4],  # применяем к -1.8 -3.2  2.6
[1,7,14],   # применяем к 1.12 4.8  14.04
[1,5,6,38],  # применяем к 50.6 6.8  16.8
])
```

need cerate def
(нужно создать функцию)
которая будет проверять приведенное значение из Х к целому
проверять его, если есть в массиве соответствий то не менять, иначе брать случайное значение из cons_data

```
def test_func(x,cons_data ):
```

need return res

```
[-1.8, 1.12, 50.6] == check -1.8 =>int = -2 not [1,4] => give random 1 or 4 = 4
[-1.8, 1.12, 50.6] == check 1.12 =>int = 1 In [1,7,14] => == 1.12
[-1.8, 1.12, 50.6] check 50.6 =>int = 51 not [1,5,6,38] => give random 1 or 5 or 6 or 38 = 5

res x[0] ==> [-1.8, 1.12, 50.6] ==> [4.0, 1.12, 5.0]
```

full res examle

```
res [
[4.0, 1.12, 5.0] ,
[1.0, 7.0, 14.0] ,
[1.0, 14.04, 38.0] ,
]
```

Comment: Слушайте, с английским у вас не очень. Пишите уже на русскоязычном SO по-русски.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test_func(x, cons_data):
    res = np.array(x)
    with np.nditer(res, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
        for x in it:
            if round(x[...].item()) not in cons_data[it.multi_index[1]]:
                x[...] = random.choice(cons_data[it.multi_index[1]])
    return res
```

Comment: how rewrite this function line 97 - 110 github.com/laricoins/btcpredict/blob/main/model1/train.py

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from random import randrange
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [-1.8, 1.12, 50.6],
    [-3.2, 4.8, 6.8],
    [2.6, 14.04, 16.8],
]);

cons_data = np.array([
    [1, 4],        # применяем к -1.8  -3.2  2.6
    [1, 7, 14],    # применяем к  1.12  4.8  14.04
    [1, 5, 6, 38], # применяем к  50.6  6.8  16.8
]);

def test_func(x_np, cons_data_np):
    res = []; xn = x_np.tolist();
    cdn = cons_data_np.tolist();
    for i in range(0, len(xn)):
        tmp = [];
        for n in range(0, len(xn[i])):
            if (int(round(xn[i][n])) in cdn[n]):
                tmp.append(xn[i][n]);
            else:
                tmp.append(cdn[n][randrange(0, len(cdn[n]))]);
        res.append(tmp);
    return res;
            
res = test_func(x, cons_data);
print(res);
```

Comment: how rewrite this function line 97 - 110 https://github.com/laricoins/btcpredict/blob/main/model1/train.py